# notify local cache of change in cache cluster

Tags: c#, .net, caching, appfabric, distributed-caching

I am using appfabric caching in my c# application. I have enabled local cache.

When I add, remove, update or delete an item from my cache cluster I would like to send a notification that such has occurred via my c# code. Is this possible and if so how is it achieved?

I was considering setting it up on the web.config of my application to poll looking for updates to the cache cluster but I am concerned that this may have performance issues therefore I would like to include the trigger of the notification in my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to enable notifications for invalidating/updating cached items in the local cache, then I have some good news for you: you don't have to write any C# code to achieve this, AppFabric will do it for you. See the second paragraph on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790986.aspx).

You can configure the local cache to receive notifications from the cluster, either in your [web. or app.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790880.aspx) or [in code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790857.aspx) when you instantiate a `DataCacheFactory`. You'll also need to enable notifications on the cache itself when you create it e.g.

```
New-Cache -CacheName MyCache -NotificationsEnabled true
```

The local cache will then poll the cluster for notifications; the default poll interval is 300 seconds but you can tune this in your config if you wish, depending on how volatile you believe your cached data to be.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Regarding the poll interval, are there performance implications to lower the interval to ~20 seconds? I need the local cache to reflect the cache cluster as quick as possible to achieve data accuracy.